# How to stage subsequent changes to a file that has already been staged in index?

Tags: git, git-reset, git-index

I made some changes to a file and then staged it in the index for the next commit. Then I realized that I needed some more changes to do. Instead of unstaging it, is there a way to capture these subsequent changes before finally committing?

Would it be

**git add -u filename** (as many times as I make changes to the *filename* file)

instead of

**git reset**

**git add filename**

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `git add filename` on the same file as many times as you want.

It'll always add any existing non-staged changes, regardless of whether the file already has changes in the index.

---

The `-u` flag (shortcut for `--update`) serves a different purpose. From [the man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> Update the index just where it already has an entry matching `<pathspec>`. This removes as well as modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no new files.

In other words: if `filename` has never been tracked before, `git add -u filename` won't add it to the index. But for files that are already tracked, using the `-u` flag makes no difference.

Comment: This is the right answer, and one thing that may help to visualize or remember it is that a tracked file is *already* in the index. (In fact, that's what *tracked* means: "in the index"!) Using `git add` just copies the work-tree version into the index. If it wasn't there before, it is now. If it *was* there before, it's updated now.

Comment: Really? But, doesn't the file get saved in the .git database as a blob? And,  if I change the contents of the file, isn't a new blob created since the Id of a blob is based on contents of the file?

Comment: Thanks. I now understand "git add" clearly. Yes, we can do "git add" as many times as we want on any staged file, in order to include all subsequent changes to the same file. But, behind scene, a new blob object is created every time we do "git add" to the same file, abandoning the previous blob, making the previous one dangling (waiting to be garbage collected later). That makes sense because an object ID is based on the contents of a file. So, when contents get modified (updated, appended), a new blob with a new object ID is created! We can easily check it by running a series of commands.

Answer (score 0):

### Example to show the affect of making subsequent changes to a file already staged and running "git add" on it each time

echo "new file" > newfile.txt

git add newfile.txt

git ls-files --stage    [Note the object corresponding to newfile.txt]

*100644 fa49b077972391ad58037050f2a75f74e3671e92 0       newfile.txt*

ls -Fls .git/objects/fa     [Look into the fa folder]

*1 -r--r--r-- 1 user1234 1049089  24 Mar 19 00:17 49b0779.......*

echo "adding a second line to my new file" >> newfile.txt

git add newfile.txt

git ls-files --stage    [Note the new object corresponding to newfile.txt]

*100644 9f70c3077ccb16453d0ad0c152e8c169f81d8466 0       newfile.txt*

ls -Fls .git/objects/9f     [Look into the 9f folder]

*1 -r--r--r-- 1 user1234 1049089   54 Mar 19 00:22 70c3077......*

git fsck | grep fa49b0779       [Scanning for dangling blobs]

*Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (462/462), done.
dangling blob fa49b0779....     [Found that the previous blob is now dangling!]*

git fsck | grep 9f70c3077...... [Scanning to see if the current blob is dangling]

*Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (462/462), done.
                                [Obviously, not found!]*

echo "this is the third line" >> newfile.txt            [Making more changes to newfile.txt]

git add newfile.txt

git fsck | grep 9f70c3077.....  [Scanning again for 9f70c3077......]

*Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (462/462), done.
dangling blob 9f70c3077....*

[This time, we find 9f70c3077...... is no longer the blob corresponding to newfile.txt. It's now dangling, waiting for the garbage collector to wipe it out!]